# Change visualization based on Agent Parameter

Tags: visualization, anylogic

I've a question. If I create an agent from a source block based on a database with a boolean for the sort of employee (so nurse=true & office=false for nurse employee), is there an method to change the visualization, so that the nurses are visualized as nurse and an office employee as an office employee for one agent type(without making it to difficult and make the model a lot slower).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Go to the agent representation at the top left corner inside your Employee agent . Place both representations and inside the *Visible* section, type your condition. No need to type `agent.nurse==true`, just `(nurse==true)&&(office==false)`

[image]